# How to iterate multi dimensional array and pipe each sub array to another plugin as input in Migration yml

Tags: 8, migrations

I am migrating CSV data into Nodes and Paragraphs in Drupal 8.

I have field in CSV file which has JSON data, I have written a process plugin to convert JSON data to multi-dimensional array.

I would like to know a way to pass the each sub array to my another custom process plugin. Is there any such process plugin available to pipe sub array from parental array in core `migrate` or through `migrate_plus` module.

I am looking for something similar so that it passes only sub array into the final custom process plugin.

```
  pseudo_field_country_time_zones:
    - # plugin which converts JSON data to multi dimensional array.
      plugin: country_timezones_data_formatter 
      source: timezones
    - # not sure if this is correct plugin to process array.
      plugin: sub_process 
    -
      plugin: country_timezones_paragraphs
```

You might ask why cant you process the data in the `country_timezones_paragraphs` process plugin itself. That plugin is being used by other process, so dont want to change it. Other solution for me is to write another process plugin but it will be just code duplication with foreach loop added to `country_timezones_paragraphs`.

I believe there is already a plugin available either from migrate or migrate_plus module for this scenario , but not able to identify what it is.

---

```
$input_data = '[{"zoneName":"Africa Ceuta","gmtOffset":3600,"gmtOffsetName":"UTC+01:00","abbreviation":"CET","tzName":"Central European Time"},{"zoneName":"Atlantic Canary","gmtOffset":0,"gmtOffsetName":"UTC\u00b100","abbreviation":"WET","tzName":"Western European Time"},{"zoneName":"Europe Madrid","gmtOffset":3600,"gmtOffsetName":"UTC+01:00","abbreviation":"CET","tzName":"Central European Time"}]';
```

---

Decoded JSON array.

> $decoded_array = var_dump(json_decode($input_data, TRUE));

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [zoneName] => Africa Ceuta
            [gmtOffset] => 3600
            [gmtOffsetName] => UTC+01:00
            [abbreviation] => CET
            [tzName] => Central European Time
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [zoneName] => Atlantic Canary
            [gmtOffset] => 0
            [gmtOffsetName] => UTC±00
            [abbreviation] => WET
            [tzName] => Western European Time
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [zoneName] => Europe Madrid
            [gmtOffset] => 3600
            [gmtOffsetName] => UTC+01:00
            [abbreviation] => CET
            [tzName] => Central European Time
        )

)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

There's no such process plugin in [core](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-core-migrate-process-plugins) or [migrate_plus](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-process-plugins-provided-by-migrate-plus). If you can't find what you need in those lists, you'll probably have to write a custom solution. You may want to check out [SubProcess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SubProcess.php/class/SubProcess) process plugin which may be able to work with your decoded array with minimal changes.

Comment: thank you for the response I tried the `plugin: sub_process ` already but I am unable to get the correct syntax for the iteration, can you share the syntax for my array input ?

Comment: You need to add a `process:` part to your `sub_process` plugin. To do that you really need to understand what you're trying to do with each array row. I'm not sure what `pseudo_field_country_time_zones` is or how it's used, but I don't think using pseudo fields is a suitable approach in this case. If you look at examples on [SubProcess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SubProcess.php/class/SubProcess) page, they all have a `process` step, and that needs a key like `id` or `target_id` where the value should go.